# Lost 3 of my 4 cores

Tags: 10.10, drivers, re-installation

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 since I thought the upgrade was safely possible on my working machine (programmer here). I recently got a freeze now and then, but slowly it got really annoying, when it went from once in a while to once a day. So I googled around for potential causes and re-installed the graphic driver (ATI Radeon HD 4300).

After this, I suddenly only have one core left - there should be 4, since I have an i5!

When I run Ubuntu from a live-CD everything is fine - so it is not a hardware problem...

Any ideas, what I can do without re-installing?

Per request:

```
model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67GHz
```

Comment: Can you append the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name` to your post, please?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  What makes you say you only have one core?

Comment: @psusi The command asked them to run should have returned 4 lines, one for each core. Something is awry.

Comment: Okay how about the output of `dmesg | grep -i cpu`?

Comment: How about `uname -a`? Does it show `SMP`?

Answer (score 1):

What I did to rescue my computer: I used synaptic package admin and set the fglrx to re-install. Then I added this line to my grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

I rebooted and nothing happened. Then I executed

```
update-grub
```

And THEN it worked! :)

Thanks for adding your ideas!